# Writing a negative test by using exception handling

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

Let us say I have a `login` method that's working swimmingly.  It's used in quite a number of places and saves plenty of lines of retyped code.  For all intents and purposes, it does not make sense to make this method any shorter.

Is it proper to write a negative test by using exception handling?  For example, if I wanted to ensure that a disabled user is not able to log into the system, is it too awkward to write something like:

```
begin
  login(username, password)
  fail
rescue Exception
  page.should have_text('Sorry, your account is disabled!')
end
```

If login actually succeeds, the test should fail.  And if we reach the exception, we find our error message and the test passes.

I'm wondering if this is too "clever" and may cause confusion.  What's the best way of handling a negative test case here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be testing the expected behavior so there would be no rescuing within your specs. In this case, you would want to disable the account in a `before` caluse and then ensure the exception is raised when you attempt to perform an operation (login, etc.).

Testing anything for the generic `Exception` is also a bad idea - you want to be very specific about the expected exception as a different issue could cause your specs to pass.

The code would look something like

```
expect { login(username, password) }.to raise_error LoginException
```

Comment: I'm using the raise_error matcher as you mentioned, thanks. Reference doc [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher) for anyone who needs it